# How to change uniswap router address after deployment of contract?

Tags: uniswap, bsc, pancakeswap

I deployed a contract with the wrong router address hardcoded like this:

```
    IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);
```

Now I can't remove liquidity or exchange tokens on pancakeswap. How do I work around this problem? I know it's possible because I copied this contract from ASS Coin and they obviously found a way around it.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing all of your code. If you didn't include a function for updating this router variable, then there's nothing you can do to update it

Comment: If the token pair contract was created funds should be there. In that case it might be possible to interact with the pair and mimic the router behavior for remove liquidity. See here the interactions https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L111-L119.